# Datetime with meridian indicator convert from Oracle to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

How to insert "29-SEP-22 12.00.17.225 AM" in PostgreSQL DB ?

In Oracle Table,

"29-SEP-22 12.00.17.225 AM"

In PostgreSQL Table ,  ??

How to capture above date format in PostgreSQL table ?
what will be the datatype  PostgreSQL side ?

Comment: That is not a `date` format it is `datetime`(timestamp) format.

Comment: Is it really a string (varchar2) in your Oracle table, or is it a really a date - and your client is just formatting it like that for display? If it's a date (which is actually a datetime - Oracle does't have a date-only data type) then you can `cast(... as timestamp)` if you need to to transfer elsewhere - but you haven't said how you are doing that. You might just want to query it in a different format, using `to_char()` and, say, an ISO-8601 format model, if you're going to copy-and-paste...

Comment: @AlexPoole datatype used "timestamp" in oracle, need to insert same format ( like '29-SEP-22 12.00.17.225 AM' ) in postgresql DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type would be `timestamp`. Use `to_timestamp` with format specification `dd-mon-yy hh12.mi.ss.ms pm`.
Example:

```sql
select to_timestamp('29-SEP-22 12.00.17.225 AM', 'dd-mon-yy hh12.mi.ss.ms pm');
```